# R - How can I group these categories

Tags: r

I have split my variable using the quartile function ​​and I counted how many elements there are for each category. I have considered a total of 10 quartile plus the NA category which forms another group. This is the end result.

```
    ActiveNTA        PassiveNTA
1   167              234
2   203              198
3   217              185
4   168              233
5   205              197
6   229              172
7   261              140
8   257              145
9   306              95
10  304              98
11  1                1
```

Now I need to regroup categories with less (not equal) than 50 elements into the closest category. For example, the category 11, which has just one element, in category 10, which will then have 304 + 1 and 98 + 1. this process should be iterated many times. For example:

```
6   300              300
7   10               10
8   10               10
9   10               10
10  40               40
```

should give me the following result (and consequently it reduces the number of categories):

```
6   320              320
7   50               50
```

How may I create this function in r?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you tried with a for loop and a filter with if and then add to the previous row the value?

Comment: My problem is that the loop needs to be done many times to reduce my array.

Comment: What you want is if the value is below 50 add it to the previous row. You could iterate over it until all values except the last row are above 50.